# Decoding Datamatrix as digits using pylibdmtx

Tags: python, opencv, zxing, datamatrix

I am trying to decode the digits from a Datamatrix.
This is my code

```
import cv2
from pylibdmtx.pylibdmtx import decode
a = decode(cv2.imread(dmtx.jpg'))
print(a)
```

[image: Image to be decoded]

The code runs without error. But it doesn't print anything, it gives me an empty matrix.

I couldn't understand the decode() function.

Can someone suggest me to decode as digits using pylibdmtx lib?

Comment: Are you sure your data matrix image is correctly encoded? Use an online decoder to test the image for correctness.

Comment: Actually, I'm capturing the DataMatrix from a product and doing Image processing. Yes, an Online decoder decodes correctly. But pylibdmtx doesn't. I have uploaded the Image also. Kindly Look into it. @zindarod

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to threshold the input image.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from pylibdmtx import pylibdmtx

if __name__ == '__main__':

    image = cv2.imread('image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    msg = pylibdmtx.decode(thresh)
    print(msg)
```

Comment: Yeah. It works perfectly after thresholding. Many Thanks @zindarod